# Statistics for ordinal data

Tags: normal-distribution, ordinal-data, likert, descriptive-statistics, demography

I have some **ordinal data** based on a population survey. My $X-axis$ consist of age groups $(<15 , 15-19, 20-24 . . . , 45-49$ years$)$ . On the $Y-axis$, I have proportion of certain population. And I have these kind of plots (data) for 6 different categories  . I have already constructed  frequency tables (and made histograms accordingly) but I have to analyse this data more. I need to test if my data follows a normal distribution (which I know will turn out to be not normal as it is ordianl). Since  calculating **mean** doesn't make much sense so I was wondering what other parameters and statistics that could be calculated.

It would also be helpful if any suggestions regarding software tools is given (especially most feasible to ordinal set of data) .

Comment: Do you have an end goal for the analysis? Also, it does not make sense to test for normality.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis - Ok sure, the test doesn't make sense since my data is discrete. My end goal for the analysis is to obtain a descriptive statistics for my data set.

Comment: If all you want/need is descriptive stats, you're on the right track. Plots and plenty of them are always useful in presentations. If the data is small (e.g. ~1mb), I would just use Excel's pivot tables to make plots. But I'm just lazy. Also, people love that Tableau junk too.

Comment: @Johnnyboycurtis ok. but my problem still persist.